# Open HREF link in HTML through VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel

i am trying to automate some scraping through vba. I have a number of login ids and password to which I login individually and download some data. I have managed to login to site, the next part is opening the hyperlink mentioned in the href tag (inner text). Can someone help me to set the code for the same?

Vincent

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: And include the URL if possible

Comment: <a href="https://www.somelink.iata.org/somelink14/acdm/acdm_query.asp?extid=CY730" title="ADM &amp; ACM Query" target="principal">-&nbsp;ADM &amp; ACM Query</a>

Comment: i dont have the code

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to tell with what you have provided but you maybe able to loop over  tags and test for presence of part of the href e.g.

```
Option Explicit

'<a href="somelink.iata.org/somelink14/acdm/…; title="ADM &amp; ACM Query" target="principal">-&nbsp;ADM &amp; ACM Query</a>

Public Sub Test()
   'Tools > references > add Microsoft XML and HTML Object library
    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60 ' this would be as per your version of Excel
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument

    With http
        .Open "GET", "yourURL", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Dim posts As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim post As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    Set posts = html.getElementsByTagName("a")

    For Each post In posts

        If InStr(1, post.innerText, "somelink.iata.org/somelink14/acdm") > 0 Then
           post.Click
        End If

    Next post

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try this?